# Is it possible to "store" a real-time (preferably internally) graph plotted using achartengine for re-play later?

Tags: java, android, graph, real-time, achartengine

I would like to know if there is a way to "store" the real-time graph and "replay" it back later?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `achartengine`, but the answer appears to be no.  With the exception of `TimeSeries`, the classes in the `org.achartengine.model` package do not store time data.  For example, there doesn't appear to be anything in `XYSeries#add(double, double)` that records the time it was called.

You could add your own wrapper that would record each data point along with the time offset, and write something else (possibly using `Handler#postDelayed(...)`) that could play back the stream.